# How to put RadioButtons into Form?

Tags: ios, radio-button, swiftui

I following the [link](https://thinkdiff.net/ios/how-to-create-radio-button-and-group-in-swiftui/) to create RadioButtons.

```
import SwiftUI


//MARK:- Single Radio Button Field
struct RadioButtonField: View {
    let id: String
    let label: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: CGFloat
    let isMarked:Bool
    let callback: (String)->()

    init(
        id: String,
        label:String,
        size: CGFloat = 20,
        color: Color = Color.black,
        textSize: CGFloat = 14,
        isMarked: Bool = false,
        callback: @escaping (String)->()
        ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.isMarked = isMarked
        self.callback = callback
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.callback(self.id)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.isMarked ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
                Text(label)
                    .font(Font.system(size: textSize))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}

//MARK:- Group of Radio Buttons
enum Gender: String {
    case male = "Male"
    case female = "Female"
}

struct RadioButtonGroups: View {
    let callback: (String) -> ()

    @State var selectedId: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            radioMaleMajority
            radioFemaleMajority
        }
    }

    var radioMaleMajority: some View {
        RadioButtonField(
            id: Gender.male.rawValue,
            label: Gender.male.rawValue,
            isMarked: selectedId == Gender.male.rawValue ? true : false,
            callback: radioGroupCallback
        )
    }

    var radioFemaleMajority: some View {
        RadioButtonField(
            id: Gender.female.rawValue,
            label: Gender.female.rawValue,
            isMarked: selectedId == Gender.female.rawValue ? true : false,
            callback: radioGroupCallback
        )
    }

    func radioGroupCallback(id: String) {
        selectedId = id
        callback(id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Gender")
                .font(Font.headline)
            RadioButtonGroups { selected in
                print("Selected Gender is: \(selected)")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

The code above works well. But when I put the `HStack` of `RadioButtons` into `Form`, the `RadioButtons` does not work. I cannot select the `RadioButtons` in this situation. The code is as following:

```
Form {
    HStack {
        Text("Gender")
            .font(Font.headline)
        RadioButtonGroups { selected in
            print("Selected Gender is: \(selected)")
        }
    }.padding()
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can layout priority solve this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead the following body for `RadioButtonField` (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
        Image(systemName: self.isMarked ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
        Text(label)
            .font(Font.system(size: textSize))
        Spacer()
    }.foregroundColor(self.color)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.callback(self.id)
    }
}
```